# Positioning inline elements with CSS

Tags: css

I would like to position #myLabel on the far left of #myDiv, and #myA on the far right of #myDiv, and keep them on the same line.  I understand that I can make #myLabel and #myA block elements and floating them left and right.  Is there a more suitable way to do this?

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:500px">
   <label id="myLabel">My Label</label>
   <a id="myA" href="clickme.html">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The other way to do it is with element set to absolute or relative positions. But floats just seem to be a better way to do it.

Comment: @frenchie.  Thanks.  You are probably right.  I have always struggled with inline verse block verse inline-block elements, and trying to get my arms around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating should work fine, but you could also use absolute positioning.

```
#myDiv {
    position: relative;
}
#myLabel {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
#myA {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/gaCQp/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have dummy solution how you could do it without absolute position and without floating:

```
#myLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#myA {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 50%;
}
#myDiv {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

here's is an example:

http://jsbin.com/alidim/2/edit

But don't forget that you have to avoid white space issue in inline-block elements :)